# Get Role by Author - Discord Bot Java

Tags: java, discord, chatbot, roles, discord-jda

Is there any way to get the roles from Author or something like this ?

```java
 if (content.equalsIgnoreCase("hello")){
            channel.sendMessage("Hello **" + author + "**\nAre you ready ?\nYour roles are: " + role).queue();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getMember()` instead of `getAuthor()`.

You can then use `Member#getRoles`:

```java
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
  for (Role role : event.getMember().getRoles()) {
    System.out.println("Role: " + role.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this one but no output. Im learning java right now in the school. And this bot is my home project to learn java.  Cause is : **Methode 'getMember()' is annotated as 'nullable'**

Comment: @Detrua You should ask your teacher about debugging practices - debugging is the process by which we find bugs in a program. Often this is done by tracking the execution of the code somehow, to figure out why nothing is happening. In this specific case, you will want to check that your method is actually called and that getRoles() is not returning an empty list.